# Rbenv shim fallback to system package

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I have two active projects on my local machine, running on different ruby versions. Both projects use wicked_pdf with wkhtmltopdf dependency, however project A is using gem `wkhtmltopdf-binary` and project B is relying on system level installation of `wkhtmltopdf` package (it is deployed from alpine image, so `wkhtmltopdf-binary` does not work there).

Now the fun bit. Because of `wkhtmltopdf-binary` gem in project A, rbenv created a shim for `wkhtmltopdf` which is much higher in my PATH than system-level installation. So, when I try to run tests in project B, it is now complaining that `wkhtmltopdf` is not present in ruby 3.0.5 (present in 3.1.1), despite being installed system-wide.

Is there any way of telling rbenv to fallback to system installation when bin is not available for current ruby version? Or do I need to do some internal hackery in project B only to get around alpine limitations?

Comment: you could configure path to executable for project B `WickedPdf.config = {exe_path: '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'}`